# When designing an app for android tablets, are mdpi and dpi the same thing?

Tags: android, tablet

I'm a graphic designer and am designing an android app for a client for the first time. Currently my comps are 1280x752 pixels (found these dimensions here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/09/designing-for-android-tablets/) for a 10" tab, however I can't find out what the dimensions should be for the 7" tab?? The client wants to see some of the comps sized down to the 7" size.

I've read through the android developer app and everything is in "mdpi". is that the same as dpi?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Android screen design is no straight forward process like for the IPhone for example. Android devices can come in (almost) all densities (XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI, LDPI) and Sizes.

You have to understand the principles of android screen-layouts to understand how to design apps for android. [This documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is a good starting point, also the [Android Design Page](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) has a lot to offer.

Or talk directly to the developer which has to turn your design into code - what resolutions does he need etc.